# Report Type – Ant Deployment Errors (Invalid Field Name & Duplicate Value Found)

Tags: reporting, deployment, ant, custom-report-type, custom-reports

I am trying to deploy Reports and Dashboards via Ant tool.

I get this error for Report Type

> 1. reports/JMT_Reports/Expiry_and_Renewal_Status.report -- Error: Invalid field name: Lease_Unit__c$Lease_End_Date_formula__c
> 2. reports/Junction_Reports/This_Month_Outstanding_Invoices.report -- Error: duplicate value found: < unknown> duplicates value on record with id: < unknown>

For 1. I checked on object Lease_Unit__c there is field present Lease_End_Date_formula__c

for 2. **This_Month_Outstanding_Invoices-**
This is Matrix Report
xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <columns>
        <field>CUST_OWNER_NAME</field>
    </columns>
    <columns>
        <field>CUST_NAME</field>
    </columns>
    <columns>
        <field>Invoice__c.Amount__c</field>
    </columns>
    <columns>
        <field>Invoice__c.Amount_Paid__c</field>
    </columns>
    <columns>
        <field>Invoice__c.Billing_Type__c</field>
    </columns>
    <columns>
        <aggregateTypes>Sum</aggregateTypes>
        <field>Invoice__c.Outstanding_Amount__c</field>
    </columns>
    <columns>
        <field>Invoice__c.Invoice_Date__c</field>
    </columns>
    <filter>
        <criteriaItems>
            <column>Invoice__c.Outstanding_Amount__c</column>
            <isUnlocked>true</isUnlocked>
            <operator>notEqual</operator>
            <value>0</value>
        </criteriaItems>
        <criteriaItems>
            <column>Invoice__c.Voided__c</column>
            <isUnlocked>true</isUnlocked>
            <operator>notEqual</operator>
            <value>1</value>
        </criteriaItems>
    </filter>
    <format>Matrix</format>
    <groupingsAcross>
        <dateGranularity>Day</dateGranularity>
        <field>Invoice__c.Payment_Due_Date__c</field>
        <sortOrder>Asc</sortOrder>
    </groupingsAcross>
    <groupingsDown>
        <dateGranularity>Day</dateGranularity>
        <field>Invoice__c.Account__c</field>
        <sortOrder>Asc</sortOrder>
    </groupingsDown>
    <name>This Month Outstanding Invoices</name>
    <params>
        <name>co</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </params>
    <reportType>CustomEntity$Invoice__c</reportType>
    <scope>organization</scope>
    <showDetails>true</showDetails>
    <timeFrameFilter>
        <dateColumn>Invoice__c.Invoice_Date__c</dateColumn>
        <endDate>2017-03-31</endDate>
        <interval>INTERVAL_CUSTOM</interval>
        <startDate>2017-01-01</startDate>
    </timeFrameFilter>
</Report>
```

Comment: have you checked this `Lease_End_Date_formula__c` field on your target org.?

Comment: Yes it is there

Comment: For 2 - Have you checked that you have not set the "track field history" for this field in object?

Answer (score 5):

Little late for the person who asked, but I just had to solve this issue the problem is if you don't bring the updated ReportType along with the new reports. It seems to throw this error.

You can include the ReportType in package.xml like this:

```
<types>
    <members>ReportType_API_Name</members>
    <name>ReportType</name>
</types>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the field is not in the report type, it will throw this error too.